# Returning value that represents the minimum value in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I used a minifs to find the minimum cost in a column of data. However, I now need to understand how many pounds were purchased at that minimum value.

So essentially, for Example Description 1 need a formula to return 793.66 since that was the quantity produced at 5.33

[image]

Comment: Use SUMIFS or INDEX/MATCH with your existing MINIFS as the matching criterion.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like - =INDEX(B1:B3,MATCH(MIN(C1:C3),C1:C3))

[image]